# Does the 4.4.1 update improve 3rd-party camera apps or are the enhancements just to the stock camera app?

Tags: camera, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

The new minor update to Kit Kat is apparently all about improvements to the camera on the Nexus 5. The [official Nexus G+ page](https://plus.google.com/+Nexus/posts/YW8sTPpVN8W) says:

> It improves the camera with faster focusing, especially in low light, faster white balancing, for truer colors, the ability to pinch-zoom the viewfinder in HDR+ mode and less shutter lag.

Will I see these improvements when I use a third-party camera app, or do they only affect the official camera app that Google ships with the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Updates of this kind are usually for the camera as a whole and not just app centered. For a detailed analysis I suggest you read [this](http://www.theverge.com/2013/12/5/5175568/fixing-the-nexus-5-android-4-4-1-improves-camera). The update as a whole brought changes to the API the way the auto focus, White balance, etc in pictures taken as a whole. You will notice changes(for the better) in pictures taken from a 3rd party app too.